# Compare hashed password with passwords from file in php

Tags: php

Alright so I have a script where you register an account and it adds a line with your username and password in a .txt file. The problem is it's not correctly checking the password for some reason.

Here's the contents of the .txt file:

```
aa;$2y$10$VPU65Et3ndqpCuxilZSLYO5Z9hA1rHy0BVCCBRANsqzGy.TKncKNG
alan;$2y$10$69osQF6KBRfYeHRdqkkzRenXpwMMR4jIK5n0xxMJRQTFsKsgR2ZN2
ala;$2y$10$/rcufuupuBVoG216aF7kfOlkvBxwHbI1kzsFg9BbQ2fbj/OyOQmeK
```

And here's the code:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="namn"><br> Password: <input 
type="text" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in">
</form>
<?php
session_start();
$userN = $_POST['namn'];
$passW = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$userList = file ('users.txt');

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if (empty($userN) && empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        echo "Both fields are empty.";
    } else if (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        echo "Please enter your password";
    } else if (empty($userN)) {
        echo "Please enter your username.";
    } else {
        foreach($userList as $row) { 
            $parts = explode(";",$row);
                if($userN==$parts[0] && password_verify($passW, $parts[1])) {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['namn'];
                    header("Location:index.php");
                } else {
                    echo "Wrong username/password!";
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

It just says "Wrong username/password!Wrong username/password!Wrong username/password!" when I attempt to login. Hope it's nothing too glaringly obvious and a stupid question.

Please tell me if I should include anything else.

Comment: `password_verify()` takes the plaintext password as its first parameter. You are passing it the result of a `password_hash()` call. In addition, you are going to generate a `Wrong username/password!` message for every (non-matching) account in your file.

Comment: I think the first parameter of `password_verify()` should be unhashed

Comment: You're probably also including the newline character in the comparison. You'll likely want to `trim($parts[1])` to remove it.

Comment: Or you can pass `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as the second argument to the `file()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You get the weird output, because of two errors you did in your code.

**1. You used [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`pasword_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) not in the correct way**

To verify if you have the same password, you take the password from the `$_POST` and hash it via `$passW = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`. You then check if this password is in your file with the command [`password_verify($passW, $parts[1])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). The correct way anyway is, that you use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) when you **save** the password and only then. If you want to check if the password was saved you use [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) with the unhashed password:

```
$passW = $_POST['pass'];
....
if ($userN==$parts[0] && password_verify($passW, $parts[1])) {
...
```

Like this the check will work.

**2. You echo the output of your login for each iteration in your loop**

You get the text `"Wrong username/password!"` three times on each login try. This is because the line `echo "Wrong username/password!";` is inside of your `foreach` loop and your file contains three lines. Instead, you should not use the `else` block of your condition to handle the output of a wrong login attempt, because you leave the page in case of a successful login anway. So you can safely add a [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) after the redirection to stop further code execution and print out the error message in any other way. Because the check `$userN === $parts[0]` is also part of that check it was executed for each row anyway, which resulted in a wrong output.

```
foreach($userList as $row) { 
    $parts = explode(";",$row);
    if($userN === $parts[0] && password_verify($passW, $parts[1])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['namn'];
        header("Location:index.php");
        die();
    }
}
echo "Wrong username/password!";
```

Because of the [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) command the error message will only be printed if the login was not successful. Because it is outside of the `foreach` loop it will be printed only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
password_verify($passW,trim($parts[1])))
```

While I am unsure if it happened when the hash was stored or during retrieval, the password_hash had a space at the end. Trimming the hash before feeding it to password_verify fixed the issue for me.